# validation issue with character data

Tags: jquery, html

Using direct input into the W3schools validator I am getting many errors, but a lot of those errors are very similar stating things like:

character data is not allowed here:

```
var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'>");
```

(pointing at " at the end)

Also I keep getting this below which I don't quite understand what the problem is:

How about this?

```
var $options = $("<td><table class='option'><tbody><tr><td class='opt'>1. Option Type:</td></tr></tbody></table></td>");
```

Comment: W3Schools ([may their web-servers die in a fire](http://w3fools.com/)) do not have a validator. They link to the W3C validation service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are using XHTML and placing your JavaScript inline in a `<script>` element.

The simplest way to solve this is to **not use XHTML**, which brings more trouble then benefits for most people. Use HTML 4.01 Strict or the HTML 5 draft instead.

If you want to persist in using XHTML then…

In XHTML the [rules for script elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.8) change and no longer contain intrinsic CDATA (because XML doesn't support it). This means that `<` means "Start of tag" as usual and not "A less than sign". You must either use explicit CDATA markers or represent characters with special meaning (such as `<`) by character references (such as `&gt;`).

Since most XHTML is served as `text/html` you need to write your XHTML so that it is compatible with HTML parsers as well as XHTML parsers. The character reference approach will break in HTML parsing mode.

See [the HTML Compatibility Guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_4) which explain how to munge CDATA markers to be compatible with HTML and XHTML in script elements. Do note their recommendation to use external scripts.